# Override body property

Tags: css

I have

```
body
{
    color: #696969;
}
```

and

```
th.somelist
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

but the color property of body is not overridden.
How come, and how can I make it override the body selector?

**Edit:**

I also have

```
table.somelist
{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

and the code is

```
<table class="somelist">
    <tr>
        <th class="somelist">
            Top 10
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> 1. </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The *th* text is bold but #696969 and not red.

Comment: Please show some more code. Are the table cells not showing up red?

Comment: @Hristo: `!important` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Do you expect the `th.somelist` color to change the color of the `body`? That's just not how CSS works.

Comment: Wooops. I figures it out. Had a cache setting set for 1 hour, so the page wasn't actually generated. My bad.

Comment: If this question isn't really valid, perhaps it would be better to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html><head><title>test</title>
<style>
body
{
    color: #696969;
}
th.somelist 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
testing...
<table><tr><th class="somelist">should be red</th></tr>
<tr><th>should not be red</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

works on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: since "bold" is the default for TH in most browsers, you'll see the 2nd TH bold as well; that's not a bug.