# Html - Replace hx codes with equivalent

Tags: html, xslt

An existing XSL transform of XML data to a html report has a number of h3, h4, etc codes in it. This works fine as a standalone html but causes issues when placed in our web site,
hence the need to replace the heading codes with equivalents.
I tried the following (from [Override body property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875759/override-body-property) ) with no joy, i.e. text is normal. Where I have "p class="myh3" was a h3 before..

> > After tips on how I can add do this, define some replacements and use them in the XSL code ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p.myh3 {
            align='center' style='font-size: 14px;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;'
        }

        body {
            font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt
        }
        </style>

        <Title><xsl:value-of select='$Title'/></Title>
    </head>

<body >
     <!-- This prints in normal text ... -->
    <p class="myh3">Fixed Problems and Minor Enhancements</p>
     ... more stuff
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want - if you need help chaning the xsl code then you should show the xsl code

Answer (score 0):

Well, the contents of the HTML `style` element should be CSS, you have the right syntax in `font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt` but the wrong syntax in `align='center' style='font-size: 14px;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;'` where you probably want `font-size: 14px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;`, without the `style=` and without `align=`.

Nevertheless using semantic markup with `hn` elements for heading should be preferred to styling paragraphs as headings.

Comment: Thanks, font-size: 14px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; works, there was a typo after the center, : needed to be ; 
I agree I would prefer to use headers..